# Selecting items from ets/dets based on a function. Anyway to do in besides a tab2list |> Enum.filter?

Tags: erlang, elixir

So I'm storing items in an ets/dets table. Currently I'm doing it with postgres, and I'd like to see if it can be done without it, or if it's significantly slower.

I want to do a basic spatial query. Basically checking that an item is within X meters of the current location.

```
ets = ets.new(:table, [:named_table])
# Data looks like this: {id, lat, lng, data}

# This is the location of the requester, this changed on every query.
current_location = {lat, lng}
```

If I want all items from the ets within 50M of the request.

```
ets |> :ets.tab2list |> Enum.filter(fn {_, rlat, rlng, _} = row ->
  Haversine.distance({rlat, rlng}, current_location) < 50
end)
```

Is there any better way to do this? I can't use guards as the Haversine formula uses :math.sin/asin/sqrt.

Basically the question is. Is there any way to query an ETS/DETS table by a function? Or do I need to extract it into a list first?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `:ets.foldr` here, with the function collecting all elements that match your criteria and ignoring the rest:

```
:ets.foldr(fn {_, rlat, rlng, _}, row ->
  if Haversine.distance({rlat, rlng}, current_location) < 50 do
    [row | acc]
  else
    acc
  end
end, [], ets)
```

This will save you the overhead of constructing a list for all rows in the table first, which `:ets.tab2list` will do.

(There are some `match*` functions in `ets`, but they only accept a [match spec](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/match_spec.html) and your function cannot be converted to a match spec as it uses match operations not allowed in math specs.)

Comment: .I notice there's also a `foldr`. In my case I don't care about the order so I don't need `reverse`, but for your exmple, instead of `foldl` and `reverse`, couldn't you just use `foldr` to get in the order you want it?

Comment: Yep, `foldr` should give the same result as `foldl` + `reverse`. I'll mention that in the answer, thanks!